# AJAX not passing data to CodeIgniter Controller

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Greeting StackOverflow! I am trying to pass data to controller using AJAX, but for some reasons it doesn't.

Controller:

```
public function updateSocial($key){
        if($key != null){
            list($name, $address) = explode("&&", $key);
            $this->db->query("UPDATE social SET address = '" . $address . "' WHERE name = '" . $name . "'");
            echo "Affected rows: " . $this->db->affected_rows();
        }
    }
```

Ajax:

```
function updateSocial(name){
                var address = $("#" + name).val();
                var key = name +"&&"+ address;
                //alert(key);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>controller/updatesocial", 
                    data: key,
                    dataType: "text",  
                    cache:false,
                    success: 
                        function(data){
                            alert(data);  //as a debugging message.
                        }

                });
            }
```

and HTML:

```
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <label for="{name}">{name}</label>
                        <input id="{name}" class="form-control" name="{name}"value="{address}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-material-green pull-right" onclick="updateSocial('{name}')"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I've searched for solutions here on StackOverflow, tried everything and couldn't solve it.

If I manually enter values in url as following:

```
www.domain.com/controller/updatesocial/something&&another_something
```

it works, so the problem is not PHP-side.

What I'm trying to do: I have multiple input fields that needs to be modified individually, and I want to use AJAX to do so.

I'm sorry if same problem has been posted, but I couldn't find it. I've tried everything I could find and it doesn't work.

Comment: debug your ajax request is it hitting the right controller&action, chrome, debug, netwok tab, click filename

Comment: Using AJAX Debugger for Chrome, i get XHR Loaded (updatesocial - 200 OK - 65.0000000023283ms - 1.429KB)

Comment: I have update my answer

Comment: How does your `updateSocial()` JavaScript method look in HTML if you view the source code of your HTML page?

Comment: since you are making a get request, simply place the information passed in the `url: url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>controller/updatesocial/" + key,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function updateSocial(name){
            var address = $("#" + name).val();
            var key = name +"&&"+ address;
            //alert(key);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>controller/updatesocial/"+key, 
                dataType: "text",  
                cache:false,
                success: 
                    function(data){
                        alert(data);  //as a debugging message.
                    }

            });
        }
```

You are sending data using GET method so you have to send it by appending url and your controller will be

```
public function updateSocial(){
    $key = $this->uri_segment(3);
    if($key != null){
        list($name, $address) = explode("&&", $key);
        $this->db->query("UPDATE social SET address = '" . $address . "' WHERE name = '" . $name . "'");
        echo "Affected rows: " . $this->db->affected_rows();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

You can send data  to server by data option in ajax and the type which defines. The default type is GET method

Use " data: {name:name,address:address},"

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>controller/updatesocial", 
                    data: {name:name,address:address},
                    dataType: "text",  
                    cache:false,
                    success: 
                        function(data){
                            alert(data);  //as a debugging message.
                        }

                });
```

Answer (score 1):

It might creating problem with "&&", Try `data: encodeURIComponent(key)` in ajax.

Comment: How about this `url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>controller/updatesocial/"+encodeURIComponent(key), ` ?

Comment: With that I get 400 Bad Request

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
var key = name +"&&"+ address;
```

TO-

```
var key = name +"-"+ address;
```

Also explode on server with (-), Try it

Comment: Tried both ways, same result.

Comment: For investigate the code, try to add static path, Instead on base_url()

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know ,the problem is at you "var key",change it to : var key = "name="+name+"&"+"address="+address;

Comment: I use CodeIgniter, and it works if i manually enter the expected result from AJAX, such as www.domain.com/controller/updatesocial/something&&another_something , but the problem is that AJAX is not getting that far, for some reason.