# How can i pass a codeigniter session value through ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

is there anyway that i can pass a codeigniter session value through ajax and get results back ?my ajax request as follows

```js
$.ajax({
        method :'GET',
        url: baseUrl+'ajaxcontroller/LoadData_To_View',
        success:function(data){
        $('#item').html(data);
        console.log(data);
        },
        complete: function(){
        $('#loadingImage2').hide();
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){alert(thrownError);}
        });
```

Comment: "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31892442/4229270

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can actually! You can actually pass any variable through ajax through the **data** property but it has to be in a JSON Format. Here's the code below.

***First Example:***

```
$.ajax({
 method: 'GET',
 url: baseUrl + 'ajaxcontroller/LoadData_To_View',
 data: {
     id: "<?= $this->session->userdata('id') ?>",
     username: "<?= $this->session->userdata('email') ?>"
 },
 success: function(data) {
     $('#item').html(data);
     console.log(data);
 },
 complete: function() {
     $('#loadingImage2').hide();
 },
 error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
     alert(thrownError);
 }
```

});

**OR** you can pass the whole session like this!

```
$.ajax({
     method: 'GET',
     url: baseUrl + 'ajaxcontroller/LoadData_To_View',
     data: <?= json_encode($_SESSION) ?>,
     success: function(data) {
         $('#item').html(data);
         console.log(data);
     },
     complete: function() {
         $('#loadingImage2').hide();
     },
     error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         alert(thrownError);
     }
 });
```

What matters is you have to have your variables in a **JSON format** for it to work! A JSON Format will be translated as a multidimensional array in the server side.

Comment: Thanks i will try this and get back to you :)

Comment: Good! json_encode() converts your multidimensional array into a json object so this is a good way to do it.

Comment: @ therealadrain  Thanks